# Solving ODE equation with assumptions with SymPy

Tags: sympy, ode

I'm solving an ODE equation:

```
from sympy import *

E5 = Function('E5')
t  = Symbol('t')
ode = Eq(Derivative(E5(t), t),
        -3*E5(t)/(-10*sqrt(6) + 30)
        + sqrt(6)*E5(t)/(-10*sqrt(6) + 30)
        - 67*sqrt(2)*exp(-sqrt(3)*t/10)/(200*(-sqrt(6) + 3))
        + sqrt(3)*exp(-sqrt(3)*t/10)/(10*(-sqrt(6) + 3))
        + 47*sqrt(2)*exp(-sqrt(2)*t/10)/(200*(-sqrt(6) + 3)))
dsolve(ode)
```

and it works (after waiting few minutes), but fails once I replace `Function('E5')` with `Function('E5', real=True)` or `Symbol('t')` with `Symbol('t', real=True)`. Namely dsolve(ode) raises TypeError("eq should be an instance of Equality"). This is because dsolve(ode, simplify=False) returns False instead of an Equation. And the latter I don't know why. Is it impossible to use dsolve with assumptions? I need them because they let me symplify expressions and otherwise my expressions get too complicated and take too long to calculate.

Do you have any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: It does look like it's because the `simplify=False` version returns `False`. This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: At first I thought it could happen because only complex solution exists, but the returned solution doesn't contain any complex numbers so I believe it's a good solution in reals too.